# The difference between "said to" and "told" while turning the direct speech into the reported

Tags: reported-speech

I have the following:

> "I may not be able to meet you at the airport", he said to her.

I made up next sentence:

> He said to her (that) he might not be able to meet her at the airport.

The key says I could use he `"told her"`. Since we can't tell `"say to someone"` from `"tell someone"` exept for the fact that the first one may not take a personal object and "say" is usually followed by particle `"to"`, I wonder if I'm able to use them in the same way?

Or, maybe, I can make out which to chose by the initial verb. I mean, the example is `"said to her"`, thus I should have written `"told her"`. Similiar to that, if I had `"he said"`, I would write only `"he said (that)..."`.

Comment: I would use *told* there, but you could use either. *Told* is more direct  and is more likely to be used as a command, while "said to [someone]* is more casual, less forceful.

Comment: In contexts of reporting speech indirectly, there is no appreciable difference, apart from the fact that **told** requires an indirect object. He said he was arriving at 9AM.  He told *me|her|him|them|us|you* he was arriving at 9AM.  "He told he was arriving at 9AM" would be ungrammatical.